# Is the point correctly said to be real when coordinates are at infinity

Tags: conic-sections

This is a statent that I've read under the topic of parabola :

"The parabola has 2 real focii situated on its axis, one of which is at infinity, where the corresponding directrix is also at infinity"

Here's where I don't understand,how can the the other focii be called as real when the coordinates is obviously at infinity ?

Is this concept inaccurate or my concept is ? Please clarify if you can.

Comment: Probably they are real in the sense they are not complex.

Comment: Oh !! So the factor of infinity need not be taken into account ?

Comment: There is no infinity in $\Bbb R$ nor in $\Bbb R^2$. Whoever wrote that stuff in the quotes should be sentenced to walk to infinity, to show us where it is.